# Nested for loop to generate side-by-side plots

Tags: r

I would like to be able to generate normal probability (QQ) plots of:

a) the chi-square distribution

b) the t-distribution

I'd like to display these plots side-by-side (e.g. plot of chi-square on the left and plot of t-distribution on the right).

I'm using a different number of degrees of freedom for each distribution.  Here is my code:

```
n = 100

par(mfrow = c(2,2))

for (i in seq(from=1, to=100, by=10)) {
  x <- rchisq(n, i)
  qqnorm(x, main = paste('Q-Q Plot ~ chi-square dist | df =', i))
}



for (j in seq(from=1, to=30, by=3)){
  y <- rt(n, j)
  qqnorm(y, main = paste('Q-Q Plot ~ t-dist | df =', j))
}
```

This works, but it builds the plots such that the t-distribution is ***beneath*** the chi-square plots.  I'd like the plots to be displayed ***side-by-side*** as the number of degrees of freedom increases.  For example:

```
chi-square (df=1)      t-dist (df=1)
chi-square (df=11)     t-dist (df=4)
chi-square (df=21)     t-dist (df=7)
...                    ...
chi-square (df=91)     t-dist (df=28)
```

I tried a nested for loop, but couldn't get it to work.  Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to put the figures in the same loop:

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
par(mfrow = c(10,2))
dfs <- cbind(seq(from=1, to=100, by=10), seq(from=1, to=30, by=3))
for (i in 1:nrow(dfs)) {
  x <- rchisq(n, dfs[i,1])
  y <- rt(n, dfs[i,2])
  qqnorm(x, main = paste('Q-Q Plot ~ chi-square dist | df =', dfs[i,2]))
  qqnorm(y, main = paste('Q-Q Plot ~ t-dist | df =', dfs[i,1]))
}
```

[image]

Comment: `@jpsmith` -- this approach builds column vectors, and looks like it results in only the last plots in the iteration.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused about what you want - you mentioned you want the plots to be displayed side-by-side. By "side-by-side" do you want the chi square plots on the left and the t-dist plots on the right? This seems to be what the table you added represents. I have edited my answer to include the `par` commands and demonstrate how this looks on my end.

Comment: I didn't have the `par` commands.  What you have works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad this worked for you